# Queries about Teradata database connection

Tags: windows, odbc, teradata, tableau-api

I am new to Teradata. 
I need to connect Teradata database through ODBC connection in Tableau. For this requirement, I have installed below software.

1) Tableau Desktop 
2) JDK 1.8 
3) Teradata Studio Express 16.0
4) Teradata ODBC Driver

My Queries are,

1) Is it possible to create Teradata database using Teradata Studio Express? If yes means, Please provide steps? 
2) How to ensure service is running for Teradata database server? 
3) I think, need to run service for Teradata Studio Express to connect database throgh ODBC Driver. Is it correct?

**Note:** I am using windows platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a 'service'. You connect to a already running **server** via its IP-address (this may be a VM on your loacal machine).

In your ODBC-Driver you create a connection to IP-Address, user, pasword. This ODBC-connection can be used from whatever Client you want to use, e.g. Tableau. Studio Express uses JDBC. Use similar parameters in configuration for a Connection.

The data space (which the server grants access to) is divided into databases, which you create via SQL-commands (create database ...) or from TD-Studio Administrative-View.